# i getting error Cannot read property 'channels' of undefined

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm getting an error `Cannot read property 'channels' of undefined`

> (node:2632) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read
> property 'channels' of undefined
> at updateMembers (C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\Episode 50\commands\Main-Commands\Mod\member-count.js:5:31)
> at module.exports (C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\Episode 50\commands\Main-Commands\Mod\member-count.js:13:5)
> at Client. (C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\Episode 50\index.js:48:5)
> at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:28)
> at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
> at WebSocketManager.triggerClientReady (C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\Episode
> 50\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:431:17)
> at WebSocketManager.checkShardsReady (C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\Episode
> 50\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:415:10)
> at WebSocketShard. (C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\Episode 50\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:197:14)
> at WebSocketShard.emit (events.js:315:20)
> at WebSocketShard.checkReady (C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\Episode 50\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:475:12)

Here is my code:

```js
module.exports = (client) => {
    const membercountchannel = '811119579580465182' 

    const updateMembers = (guild) => {
        const channel = guild.channels.cache.get(membercountchannel)
        channel.setName(`Member:- ${guild.memberCount.toLocaleString()}`) 
    }
    
    client.on('guildMemberAdd', (member) => updateMembers(member.guild))
    client.on('guildMemberRemove', (member) => updateMembers(member.guild))

    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('787083837833871400') 
    updateMembers(guild)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check the stack trace, you can see that your `updateMembers` function receives a `guild` that is undefined (`member-count.js:5:31`). On the next line you can see that it's coming from the last line (`member-count.js:13:5`): `updateMembers(guild)`.

As you define `guild` one line above, it means `client.guilds.cache.get('787083837833871400')` returns undefined. Make sure the guild ID is correct. If it is correct, you can try to [fetch the guild](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildManager?scrollTo=fetch) instead.

One more thing, you should never add event handlers inside event handlers. I think you're already in `client.on('message')`. Every time someone's using your command to update the member count, you create two new event listeners (`client.on('guildMemberAdd')` and  `client.on('guildMemberRemove')`) and it will cause issues (memory leaks). You need to handle these somewhere else, outside of your commands.

```js
module.exports = async (client) => {
  const updateMembers = (guild) => {
    const memberCountChannel = '811119579580465182';
    const channel = guild.channels.cache.get(memberCountChannel);
    channel.setName(`Member:- ${guild.memberCount.toLocaleString()}`);
  };

  try {
    const guild = await client.guilds.fetch('787083837833871400');
    updateMembers(guild);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```